# SSH slow login and slow typing from Ubuntu SSH and Windows Putty clients over wireless only

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I have a Raspberry Pi cluster of 3 Raspberry  Pis, each running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my home network (192.168.0.n). Each Raspberry  Pi has a static IP assigned through Netplan configuration.

When attempting to SSH to any of the Raspberry Pis from my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, SSH login either takes a long time or it eventually logs in but typing is very slow or unresponsive.

I have attempted this from a Windows laptop with PuTTYy on the same network and see the same behaviour eventually leading to the following error:

> Network error: Software caused connection abort

On each of the Pis running SSHD, I have set `UseDNS no` and also commented out `session optional pam_systemd.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, essentially following the steps defined on this website: https://jrs-s.net/2017/07/01/slow-ssh-logins/

My router is provided by my ISP; Sky UK.

What's bizarre is that I downloaded JuiceSSH on my Android phone and can connect to each of the Pis and run commands successfully.

I'm completely stumped. Any assistance or guidance on how to troubleshoot further will be appreciated.

Comment: Run tcpdump/wireshark and look at what packets are going back and forth. Check the logs on the RPi's. Check trhe output of `ip -s -s link show dev`, `iwconfig`. Tell us whether they are connected via wifi or cable. Check for duplicate ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Everything is connecting wirelessly at home and I can actually login directly to each Raspberry Pi but SSHing from Ubuntu Desktop and Windows laptops don't work. Shall I run the 'ip' and 'iwconfig' on each Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Today, I discovered the issue probably lies with the wireless device on my laptop. I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on the laptop and I can SSH to each of the Raspberry Pis using a wired connection. However, SSH over wireless from the same laptop fails as described above. On my Windows laptop, I can SSH (via Powershell) without any problems over the same wireless. Any suggestions on what wireless setting may be causing the problem? I'm able to browse the web over wireless without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out what was causing the SSH sessions from my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop to my Raspberry Pi cluster (affecting all 3) to hang over wireless. Turn off power management for the wireless device. First list the network device status:

```
sudo iwconfig
```

If Power Management is on, turn off by changing 3 to 2 in the following file:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf 

[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

I had to restart my laptop after the change.

Comment: If you had an issue with the wireless interface, you may had some latency with other internet connections alongside ssh. DId you experience any?

Comment: No. I didn't experience any latency with other connections. Turning off powersave feature of the network device resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the verbose of the ssh command with `ssh -vvv user@host` to find out what is the source of the delay.

The problem is caused by multiple configurations.
First, check `host` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

There would be one line with 127.0.0.1 , make sure the name of your hostname is correct in front of it. If you do not have it simply add:

```
127.0.0.1 hostname
```

If you are not sure about the hostname you can find it with:

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

After saving, there is no need to restart any service and you will see the speed up. If not try the second change.

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This file contains SSH service configuration and by default has some parameters which may not be optimal in your case. So that you can modify it, remember to use sudo ;)

`X11Forwarding` can slow down the data transfer, but usually is fine to keep it `yes`. The same with `PasswordAuthentication` which makes the connection more easy and secure. Modify and set them `no` for a test and save the file. then restart the service with:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

There is a case where you have fast command execution but slow login on ssh, and then there is a problem with authentication. To check two of the common cases are `UseDNS` and `UsePAM` in the `sshd_config` file. To check them, try:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and then add or edit if they exist as:

```
UsePAM no
UseDNS no
```

disable both at the same time to check the effect of them and do not forget to reset the `ssh` service after saving.

If you did not achieve any improvement reverse it back, and check `htop` to see if there is any suspicious process running. Check the CPU and Memory usage and may you kill them.

I won't make it longer, so sadly if the issue persists reply to this for more ideas.